# display live shell output in react dom using electron ipc

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipc

I can only access `ipcRenderer` in `preload.js` ( i disabled nodeIntegration ) so how do i display the output line by line whenever i get the output in `preload.js`

main.js

```js
function execShellCommands(commands) {
    let shellProcess = spawn("powershell.exe", [commands[0]])

    shellProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("sendToRenderer/shell-output", data.toString())
    })
    shellProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("sendToRenderer/shell-output", "stderr: " + data.toString())
    })
    shellProcess.on("exit", () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send("sendToRenderer/shell-output", "shell-exited")
        commands.shift()
        if (0 < commands.length) {
            execShellCommands(commands)
        }
    })
}
ipcMain.on("sendToElectron/execShellCommands", (event, args) => {
        execShellCommands(args)
})
```

preload.js

```js
let API = {
    execShellCommands: (action) => ipcRenderer.send("sendToElectron/execShellCommands", action)
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ElectronAPI", API)

ipcRenderer.on("sendToRenderer/shell-output", (event, output) => {
    console.log(output)
})
```

react's App.jsx

```js
ElectronAPI.execShellCommands(["spicetify apply"])
```

The output in printed one by one in the console but how do i display the output in react DOM (App.jsx) one by one in a `p` tag?

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to expose the `shell-output` listener in you `API` so your components can access it:

```
shellOutput: (callback) => {
  const channel = "sendToRenderer/shell-output";
  const subscription = (_event, output) => callback(output);

  ipcRenderer.on(channel , subscription);

  return () => {
    ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, subscription);
  };
}
```

On your components, you can now access this function with `window.ElectronAPI.shellOutput`. To log the outputs, you can create a state to store them, and set the listener with a `useEffect()`:

```
const [outputs, setOutputs] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const removeOutputListener = window.ElectronAPI.shellOutput(output => {
    setOutputs(previousOutputs => [
        ...previousOutputs,
        output
    ]);
  });

  return removeOutputListener;
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    {outputs.map((output, i) => (
      <p key={i}>{output}</p>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```